# ORDER BY [PrimaryKey] uses temporary and filesort

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

The following query is slow (0.5 seconds; tested with MySQL 5.6.21 and MariaDB 10.4.28) due to the sorting, because a temporary table and filesort is used. What is the reason for this and how can I prevent it?

```
SELECT t1.* FROM `data` AS t1 
LEFT JOIN `data_sources` AS t2 ON(t1.source_id = t2.id) 
WHERE t2.period_id = 1 
ORDER BY t1.id ASC;
```

Explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  t2  ref PRIMARY,data_sources_period_id  data_sources_period_id          8   const       1   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
    
1   SIMPLE  t1  ref data_source_id_index          data_source_id_index              8   t2.id   40889   NULL
```

Update: Changing the SELECT t1.* to SELECT * leads to huge temporary file (20 GB+) and a request timeout on both MySQL and MariaDB. I had installed MariaDB cleanly and transferred the database as a SQL dump.

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `source_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `data_source_id_index` (`source_id`);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `data_sources` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `period_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `data_sources`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `data_sources_period_id` (`period_id`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `data_sources`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN is converted to an INNER JOIN by the engine. Use `STRIGHT_JOIN` instead, to see if it gets any better.

Comment: Also note that 500ms could be reasonable just because of the amount of data that you try to fetch.

Comment: I tested your case on my local MySQL 8.2 (thank you for providing usable DDL in text). I cannot reproduce the EXPLAIN report you show. In my case, it accesses `t1` first, and there is no filesort. I conclude that something in the optimizer changed between your version of MySQL 5.6 and my version of 8.2. You should upgrade anyway, because you're using a very old version of MySQL that is no longer supported.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This makes it much better, Temporary and Filesort are gone. But isn't the "data" table then always read completely and then reduced, because the WHERE condition only reduces the 'data_sources'? That would be very bad, because the quantity in 'data' will increase greatly and only the period_id reduces the quantity to an acceptable level. If there is no other possibility, I could of course also add the period_id in data, but that would be a lot of redundancy.

Comment: @BillKarwin If there is no other option, I will probably switch to MySQL 8. But MariaDB 10.4.28 isn't that old either, it's the latest one that comes with XAMPP with PHP 8.2.

Comment: @BillKarwin it depends on cardinality/selictivity of `data_sources_period_id`. If it can help to significantly reduce the amount of data to sort, the original execution plan might be better. *filesort* alone is usually not a problem if there is no LIMIT clause. On the other hand a table scan can be faster if the result is somewhere at 10% of the table. The problem is that there is no really good execution plan, but you have to choose one anyway.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Yep, I tested with some synthetic data, because the OP didn't say what is in their table. I know that this differences in the data result in a different optimization plan.